# Explanation for regularly hearing music of no apparent source?

Tags: psychology, biology, music

My grandfather considers himself a skeptic. His wife (my grandmother) recently passed away, and ever since, he swears that he can hear distant ethereal music late at night, every night, and only in the upper story of his household.

Many people have claimed to experience similar phenomena. Although not identical, here are some other instances of similar occurences. I've seen this dubbed "clairaudience" numerous times.

[Link 1](http://carlzimmer.com/articles/2004.php?subaction=showfull&id=1177189852&archive=&start_from=&ucat=7&)

[Link 2](http://www.spiritual-experiences.com/real-spiritual-story.php?story=559)

[Link 3](http://alicelandry.suite101.com/signs-from-the-angels-a99868)

What are some psychological or neurological explanations for this type of experience?

Comment: I currently cannot find any "legitimate" case studies of this phenomena (is yahoo answers legitimate ahah?). If anyone can find any, please comment and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you provide examples of people claiming this?

Comment: @Sklivvz - I remember reading about this in a one of those "Unsolved Mysteries" type books back in the day. Let me see if I can remember the precise name for it as it was under something like "celestial sounds" or "celestial music" and people claimed to hear an angelic choir in the sky.

Comment: @Sklivvz - The question has been edited, and resources have been included.

Comment: Your first link gives the syndrome a name (Musical Hallucinosis), a description of the syndrome, an idea of the prevalence, and interview with an expert and a scientific hypothesis of the cause. What more are you hoping to get in an answer here? Let us know why you aren't happy with that so we don't just repeat it. \[See also [Auditory Hallucinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_hallucination).]

Comment: I was hoping for an all-encompassing summary of studies and of potential and confirmed psychological and neurological causes for the hallucinations. The first article only showcases the work of one researcher. The Wikipedia link however, does a decent job at presenting potential causes.

Comment: I don't have time to look for links right now, but Oliver Sacks is a neurologist who has written about this phenomenon. I think it was a chapter in "The man who mistook his wife for a hat", but I'd guess there's even more in his new book, "Musicophilia: Tales of music and the brain".

Comment: I'm just curious why you mention the fact that your grandmother died? Why is this related to his recent auditory experiences? You or your grandfather are already building a tie that is not necessarily there.

Comment: He is claiming that his recent experiences are directly due to his wife's passing. I'm trying to show otherwise.

Comment: Tinnitus?  For some people this is ringing in the ears when there is no noise.  But some people report other sounds, like music.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus